# Polar form of imaginary number

Tags: vectors

can someone please help me with this:

Select k, soo that vector c = (11,1,k) linear combination of vectors a = (4,2,3) and b = (-1, 1, 2).

Thx

Comment: There are no imaginary numbers, the wording *Polar form of imaginary numbers* is misleading. Write a new text please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

(11,1,k) = a(4,2,3) + b(-1,1,2)

11=4a-b
11=4a-1+2a
12=6a
a=2

1=2a+b
1=4+b
b=-3

k=3a+2b
k=6-6
k=0